# How to change tinymce editor font style and size on the fly?

Tags: tinymce

tinymce's [FAQ explains](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css) how to change the editor's **default** font style by referencing a custom `content_css` file.

But I'd like to change the editor's font style on the fly programmatically. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but requires some knowledge.

You will need to call something like

```
self.switchStyle(url, ed);
```

where switchStyle is

```
    // url is the url to the stylesheet file to be added to the editor iframes head
    // ed is the editor object or editor id
    switchStyle: function(url, ed) {

        if (typeof ed != 'object') {
            ed = tinymce.get(ed);
        }

                    //replace the custom content_css if set
        var url_to_replace = ed.getParam('content_css');

        var doc = ed.getDoc();
        var $doc = $(doc);

        var sheets_urls = [];

        if (url_to_replace){
            sheets_urls.push(url_to_replace);
        }

        // remove all stylesheets from sheets_urls
        $doc.find('link').each(function() {
            if (tinymce.inArray(sheets_urls, $(this).attr('href').split('?')[0]) !== -1) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });

        var link  = doc.createElement('link');
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        link.href = url;

        // setstylesheet
        $doc.find('head:first').append(link);
    },
```